# Unset NODE_DEBUG variable

Tags: node.js, shell, request

I set `NODE_DEBUG` environment variable to `request`:

```
export NODE_DEBUG=request
```

Now I want to unset it.

```
export NODE_DEBUG=""
```

I tried the command above, but the Node processes still output request debug messages.

Did I do something wrong? How can I prevent messages like below?

```
REQUEST:  { host: 'api......com',
  port: ...,
  path: '/...',
  method: 'get',
  headers: 
   {...}
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {...}
```

Comment: try `unset NODE_DEBUG`

Comment: @vinayr I still get these debug messages...

Comment: Could it be that your node script itself sets `NODE_DEBUG` using `process.env`? Or if not, could it be that you have a shell script that runs node and does this inside the script? Can you try `delete process.env['NODE_DEBUG']` as the first line of your js code?

Comment: @NitzanShaked My bad, another module was setting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case was that I was using another library that was having `debug: true` flag. Probably, it was setting `NODE_DEBUG="request"` on runtime.

```
var apiClient = new Foo({
   debug: true
});
```

By removing `debug: true` or setting it to `false`, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 2):

try `unset NODE_DEBUG`

This will do just what it sounds like: "unset" this environment variable.

(*credit goes to @vinayr's comment for this answer, but I'm putting it here for easier discovery*)

Answer (score 0):

I'm extremely late but for anyone who hasn't solved it, run `set NODE_DEBUG= node <file>` in your command line and that should fix it, at least it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

> To Set Variable :

**`export NODE_ENV = production`**

> To Check value of exported variable :

**`echo $NODE_ENV`**

> To show all exported variables :

**`export -p`**

it will display list of variables like

declare -x NODE_ENV="production"

> To Unset Variable :

**`unset NODE_ENV`**